# MySQL workbench error "Operand should contain 1 column" for TimeDiff function

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find difference between StartTime(by default it is varchar) and EndTime(by default it is varchar) as ElapsedTime in mySQL.
So tried the below to convert the datatype and update the ElapsedTime column

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
update DB.Table_name
set ElapsedTime = 
(
select ElapsedTime, 
TIMEDIFF
(
((str_to_date(EndTime, '%d-%m-%Y:%H:%i:%s'))),
((str_to_date(StartTime, '%d-%m-%Y:%H:%i:%s')))
) as diff
);
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

Getting error

> Operand should contain 1 column

Comment: ```str_to_date()``` with your second parameter can only be used if the date is in this format: ```dd-mm-yyyy```. also, check the timediff function you use: ```timediff(time1, time2)``` which should be: ```timediff(str_to_date(EndTime, '%d-%m-%Y:%H:%i:%s'), str_to_date(StartTime, '%d-%m-%Y:%H:%i:%s'))```. so, check by removing those brackets.

Comment: Your subquery selects 2 columns (`ElapsedTime` and `diff`) which cannot be placed into single column.

Comment: TimeDiff needs a time unit as first parameter

Comment: @IbrahimHammed Have tried it, but no luck. the same query works fine in SELECT statement. but not able to UPDATE  and SET the existing column

Comment: @Akina HI, If I remove ElapsedTime and SELECT only TIMEDIFF I get " Truncated Incorrect Time value '1033:57:56' "

Comment: Max. value for TIME datatype is '838:59:59'. Get the difference in second (TIMESTAMPDIFF) and format programmatically.

Comment: since the endtime and starttime are varchar, try cast them to datetime. Like ```timediff(cast(str_to_date(EndTime, '%d-%m-%Y:%H:%i:%s') AS DATETIME), cast(str_to_date(StartTime, '%d-%m-%Y:%H:%i:%s') AS DATETIME)```

Comment: update EDR_Delivery.Duplicate_userhistory
set ElapsedTime =
TIMEDIFF
(
cast(str_to_date(EndDateTime, '%d-%m-%Y:%H:%i:%s') AS DATETIME), 
cast(str_to_date(StartDateTime, '%d-%m-%Y:%H:%i:%s') AS DATETIME)
);

When I try this to update a existing column, I get below error
" Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect time value: '1030:57:56' "
Please help